# How does Angular two-way-data-binding work without a component property?

Tags: angular

I implemented the following set in my template:

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="something" />
<span *ngIf="something">I'm shown when the checkbox is checked!</span>
```

I have *not* declared a variable called `something` anywhere in my component. Still the checkbox and span are working as expected. Can someone please explain how this can be? Is some property created under the hood? Where and when is this happening?

I'm using WebStorm and a Chrome browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property is created on your component class, which is nothing more than an object. If a property does not exist on an object it will return as `undefined`, which will resolve to `false`. When you check the checkbox, the `ngModel` will set `componentIntance.something` to `true`. At this point the property will be there, when you uncheck the checkbox after this, the property will still be there, but will now be `false`.

What you are doing there though, does not work anymore with the latest angular versions and with the strict template check turned on. The compiler will detect that the `something` property is not declared on the component class and will throw an error during compile phase